# Ms Access query Where

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to find have to filter my query, in order to show me result from this month and the last month.

```
WHERE t.AllDate Between Date() - 60 and Date()
```

My code so far is this, but it roll back 60 days.

I need to have result for all the last month.

Thank you.

Comment: Pretend today's date is May 31:st, which dates do you want result from?

Comment: April 1 2018- May 31 2018... If today's date is May 10 2018, the result will be this month and the last month, so April 1 2018 - May 10 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be simpler this way:

```
WHERE DateDiff("m", t.AllDate, Date()) < 2
```

Comment: Yes it is indeed :)

Comment: It is fine... The best part is that it is showing if a user has added by mistake future dates!!!

Answer (score 3):

If the question is

> How to get the date of the first day of the **previous** month ?

You can do this in MS Access SQL :

```
DateSerial(Year(DateAdd('m',-1,Date())), Month(DateAdd('m',-1,Date())),1)
```

Right now it returns `1/04/2018`

Your query becomes :

```
WHERE t.AllDate Between DateSerial(Year(DateAdd('m',-1,Date())), Month(DateAdd('m',-1,Date())),1) 
                    and Date()
```

With this trick you will always get the right year and month, even if you run it in January.

Comment: If date is January 10 2018,will I get the result from Decenber 1 2017?

Comment: @YvetteLee check Gustav's answer also. In your context it is probably simpler